# Spring Data is not scanning my MongoDb repositories, why?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a demo app showcasing various practices. It inserts data in a MySQL database AND in a MongoDb database.

It used to show these lines in logs :

```
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDb repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

But now, after various changes (including introducing some H2 in-memory testing), it shows only :

```
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
```

and my MongoDb repository is not scanned.

As far as I can see, my MongoDb conf hasn't changed but maybe adding some H2 dependencies or some other implicit change has disabled mongodb boostrapping, how can I restore my MongoDb scanning/bootstrapping ?

Here is my actual apparently ignored MongoDb conf :

application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=police-assurance-database

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

MongoDBConfiguration :

```java
package fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mongodb.config;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mongodb.PoliceAssuranceSpringDataMongoOrderRepository;

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = PoliceAssuranceSpringDataMongoOrderRepository.class)
public class MongoDBConfiguration {
}
```

PoliceAssuranceSpringDataMongoOrderRepository  :

```java
package fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mongodb;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mongodb.entity.PoliceAssuranceMongo;

public interface PoliceAssuranceSpringDataMongoOrderRepository extends MongoRepository<PoliceAssuranceMongo, Integer> {
    List<PoliceAssuranceMongo> findByNom(String nom);
}
```

extract from starting log showing the repository is not scanned :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'fr.tristan.demoassurance.infrastructure.repository.mongodb.PoliceAssuranceSpringDataMongoOrderRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

my declared dependencies :

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after carefully redacting this question, there was only one place left to investigate, so I found what the problem was. Here it is, if it can be useful to someone else.

In my various experiments, I had duplicate the MongoDb conf exclusion in the case of a local H2 test, it was both in :

My test launch :

```java
@SpringBootTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class DemoAssuranceServiceIntegrationTest {
```

And in my conditional `application-local-test.properties` :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude= \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration, \
  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration
```

Where it should be only in my conditional conf.